# Looking for WPF/Silverlight 'device ring' example

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0

I'm looking for an example of a 'device ring', somewhat like the one used in [Live Mesh](http://www.mesh.com) (anything in a ring will do) in XAML (WPF/Silverlight). Preferably with demo code or open-source so I can have a look at how things work under the cover. Other animations, like resizing of the elements if they move around the ring, are a nice extra, but are not necessary.

I'm pretty sure quite a few people are looking for this kind of functionality (let's think about showing books, movies, ...), but somehow I can't really find any good examples. Any good pointers to examples are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Silverlight 4, you would use the new PathListBox control.  [.toolbox has a good tutorial](http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/pathlistbox/default.aspx).

Comment: Looks really nice. Pretty sure we can make something of that. +1
I'll leave it open for a bit longer to see if there are any other possibilities for SL3.